# Distributing Identical Candy and Cookies to Children

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can I distribute $6$ identical cookies and $6$ identical candies to $4$ children, if each child must receive at least $1$ of each type of item?

I heard of a strategy called stars and stripes but I don't really understand it.  Thanks for posting a solution!

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) for a way to get started

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can start by giving every child one of each treat and then restate the problem as distributing 2 cookies and 2 candies to 4 children. And proceed with a Stars and Bars problem from there. I think you would have to do it twice, once for cookies and once for candies, but I might be wrong on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment...

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can start by giving every child one of each treat and then restate the problem as distributing 2 cookies and 2 candies to 4 children. And proceed with a Stars and Bars problem from there. I think you would have to do it twice, once for cookies and once for candies, but I might be wrong on that.

For example, the number of ways to distribute the two identical cookies among 4 children is to imagine 3 vertical lines (bars) separating a space into 4 children. And then how many ways are there to arrange the 2 cookies and 3 bars:

00|||, 0|0||,  0||0|, 0|||0,  |00||,  |0|0|,  |0||0,  ||00|,  ||0|0,  |||00

And this formula is(arrangements with repeated elements): $$\frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$$
Similarly there would be 10 ways to distribute the candies, giving 100 total distributions I believe.